# running pyspark with dependency package like numpy, pandas and scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark

I am recently starting to use pyspark to use the scikit-learn. However, we don't have permission to install the dependency package like numpy in the worker node.
Is it possible that we package a virtualenv and use --py-files to dynamically send to the worker and somehow extract it and tell spark to use my own python (with the dependency).
Appreciate any comment.

Thanks

Comment: Pylab stack comes with relatively complex dependencies so simple copy of an environment may be not sufficient. Moreover it is few hundred megabytes that have to be transfered for each task. The best approach is probably to  ask an administrator to install these globally or provide isolated environment. If it is not possible but you have access to pip on worker machines you can try to use `forEachPartition` to install dependencies in the user space.

Comment: Thanks. Wonder after I manage to install dependencies in my user space, how could I tell the python to use the dependencies in my space for pyspark.

Comment: If packages are installed using `pip install --user ...` it should already on the path. If not you can always use `sys.path.append`.

Comment: @Mike: I'm having the same issue. May I know how you resolve it?

Answer (score 4):

How to properly load a virtual environment to the master and all the slave workers:

```
virtualenv venv --relocatable
cd venv 
zip -qr ../venv.zip *

PYSPARK_PYTHON=./SP/bin/python spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./SP/bin/python --driver-memory 4G --archives venv.zip#SP filename.py
```

Comment: This answer was immensely helpful! It is worth mentioning a few additional points for future readers.

Comment: The first point is that `SP` is a variable representing the name of the unzip folder of the archive provided, you can use `MYFOO` here as long as it follows the format `uri_to_archive/archivename.extension#MYFOO`.

Comment: The second point is that if the venv will be used frequently, it's worth loading to hdfs via `hadoop fs -copyFromLocal -f uri_to_archive/archivename.extension /hdfspathhere/archivename.extension`. Then you can reference the path in your command as `PYSPARK_PYTHON=./MYFOO/bin/python spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./MYFOO/bin/python --driver-memory 4G --archives hdfs://<hdfshost>/hdfspathhere/archivename.extension#MYFOO filename.py`.

Comment: The third point is that this approach works with `*.tar.gz` archives, not just `*.zip` archives.